# Find the Laplace transform of this function $f(t)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I'm pretty confused trying to find this Laplace transform:

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}2, & 0\leq t < 1 \\ 2+t, & 1\leq t < 2   \\ 0, & 2\leq t < \infty  \end{cases}$$

I know that I can represent this function as the sum of different step functions, but I'm not able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the Heaviside step function, which is defined as follows:
$$\mathscr U(t-a) = \cases{1 &$0 \leq t \leq a$\\1 & $t\geq a$}.$$
Then, as the function $f$ is defined for $t \geq 0$ we can write:
$$f(t) = 2 +t\mathscr U(t-1) -(t+2)\mathscr U(t-2). $$
Now apply the theorem:
$$\mathcal L(f(t-a)\mathscr U(t-a))(s) = e^{-at}\mathcal L(f(t))(s),$$
which is very easy to prove. Moreover, we have an interesting result:
$$\mathcal L(h(t)\mathscr U(t-a))(s) = e^{-at}\mathcal L(f(t+a))(s).$$

Answer (score 1):

You have 
$${\mathcal L}(f)(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f(x)\, dx
= \int_0^1 e^{-sx} f(x)\, dx +  \int_1^2 e^{-sx} f(x)\, dx +  \int_2^\infty e^{-sx} f(x)\, dx.$$
Can you do the rest?

Comment: Is it really = before the last integral?

Comment: Shift key omission.